# How to export SPSS graphs so they can be edited

Tags: spss

I recently switched to SPSS v20. Now when I export graphs to a DOC file the graphs are images. When I export from my earlier version of SPSS the graphs can be edited. Can anyone tell me how to export editable graphs with V20? Thanks!

Comment: Edit the graphs in word? What filetype are you exporting the graphs too (or copy and paste)?

Comment: For SPSS resources, please follow the link in our FAQ, Joel.

Comment: See this question too, which is nearly identical http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17167/how-to-edit-features-of-a-chart-from-spss-in-ms-word